# 500 error. Source of the bug : a Repository (Symfony3)

Tags: controller, repository, symfony

I encountered the problem explicitly suggested in the title.

I don't know if my code is important here because I precisely found that it was a mere $repository->findAll() which was causing the problem, in one function of a controller. In fact, it works when I'm in a dev environment, or when I turn the debug mode of the prod environment on. I give it anyways (it is very short and simple) :

```
public function listAction(Request $request){

    $rep = $em->getRepository('MRPlatformBundle:Person');

    $persons = $rep->findAll();
-------------------------^

    $data=array(
          'persons' => $persons
    );

    return $this->render('MRPlatformBundle:Search:list.html.twig', $data);

}
```

The thing is that it isn't only the findAll() : findBy, findOneBy, etc (even custom ones), nothing works.

I would be very grateful, if someone had the answer to that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($rep);` ? To see if you are not getting `false`/`null`

Comment: You could also dump it in your Twig file like so: `{{ dump(data) }}`, presuming you pass to the Twig file like so: `'data' => $data,`

Comment: The thing is that it is the calling of the rep function which is causing the 500, so that var_dump can't do anything, because of course it happens after the function being called. Incredible error, like a cherry on the cake.. (a big one, a big site..). I hope I didn't miss something very obvious..

Comment: And Thank you for you answers, the two of you.

Comment: I `var_dump`ed my rep, and it was fine by the way

Comment: Ok, sorry for the queue of comments but I found out that it was my class which was the mere source of the problem. If I changed the rep for another simple class (without much relation to other ones), it worked. I assume that it is a matter of infinite looping, because of persist-cascading (?)

Comment: Problem solved ! For anyone who encountered the same bug, try the following symfony commands : 

`php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata --env=prod;`,
`php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query --env=prod;` and
`php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result --env=prod;`